# Multiple Models Reference Single Schema

Tags: google-bigquery, data-warehouse, dbt

I've just started building our BigQuery data warehouse transformations with DBT, so far i love every bit of it.

There is a requirement to incrementally merge 3 source tables in one final fact table.
Example sale, deliverynotes, invoices -----> to be merged to sale_transactions schema.

When i created two models to point in same schema i get this error

```
Compilation Error
  dbt found two resources with the database representation "`iprocure- 
  edw`.`iprocure_wh_marts`.`sale_transactions`".
  dbt cannot create two resources with identical database representations. To fix this,
  change the configuration of one of these resources:
  - model.sales_marketing.int_sales_saletransactions (models/intermediate/sales/int_sales_saletransactions.sql)
  - model.sales_marketing.int_invoiced_saletransactions (models/intermediate/sales/int_invoiced_saletransactions.sql)
```

How can one achieve this requirement?

Comment: Can you add some code here? I don’t understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what is the input data and what is the expected output? check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question please so we can help you.